How to read "objectsid" from Active Directory using LDAP connection?
I'm writing a service that will fetch users from Active Directory server (on-premise, but I am not sure if this is relevant)
The code is written in C#.
I'm using an LDAP connection like this:
var authType = AuthType.Basic;
var connection = new LdapConnection(
    new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(hostNameOrIP, portNumber),
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain), authType);      
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
connection.Bind();

I can get Users from Active Directory, but when I try to parse the "objectguid" attribute from a user from Base64 to string I get "junk"
"objectguid": [
   "jNXa6wSDYU6cy4peVH8GuQ=="
],

I read this post: How to get objectSid value programmaticaly from Active Directory?
and I understand that the objectguid is a value in binary and base64 encoded
I tried to convert the script in the post to C# using chatGPT and I got this code:
    private void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            string base64ObjectSid = "jNXa6wSDYU6cy4peVH8GuQ==";

            // Decode base64 to byte array
            byte[] objectSidBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ObjectSid);

            // Extract components from the byte array
            int revision = objectSidBytes[0];
            int subAuthorityCount = objectSidBytes[1];

            // Construct the SID string
            string sidString = $"S-{revision}-{objectSidBytes[7]}";


            for (int i = 0; i < subAuthorityCount; i++)
            {
                int subAuthorityStartIndex = 8 + i * 4;
                uint subAuthorityValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(objectSidBytes, subAuthorityStartIndex);
                sidString += $"-{subAuthorityValue}";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"UserName: {userName}, Decoded SID: {sidString}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

but it doesn't work. I get an exception :

Index was out of range. It must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'startIndex')

Does anyone know how to parse the objectguid value from AD to a readable string?
Thanks

You have an overflowing problem. Your input of jNXa6wSDYU6cy4peVH8GuQ== is a base64 string. You are decoding it via
byte[] objectSidBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ObjectSid);

so you will have a byte array. Your first two bytes have some special meaning:
            // Extract components from the byte array
            int revision = objectSidBytes[0];
            int subAuthorityCount = objectSidBytes[1];

and your decoded string looks like
"\u008cÕÚë\u0004\u0083aN\u009cË\u008a^T\u007f\u0006¹"

Now, what you will necessarily need is to check the size of your byte array, to see how many bytes you have in your decoded string. Checking this (in Javascript because I want it to be a snippet)


console.log(new Blob([atob("jNXa6wSDYU6cy4peVH8GuQ==")]).size)



it is clear that this has a size of 25.
So, let's see this code:
 public static string ConvertSidByteValueToStringValue(Byte[] sidBytes)
        {
            short sSubAuthorityCount = 0;
            StringBuilder strSid = new StringBuilder();
            strSid.Append("S-");
            try
            {
                // Add SID revision.
                strSid.Append(sidBytes[0].ToString());

                sSubAuthorityCount = Convert.ToInt16(sidBytes[1]);

                // Next six bytes are SID authority value.
                if (sidBytes[2] != 0 || sidBytes[3] != 0)
                {
                    string strAuth = String.Format("0x{0:2x}{1:2x}{2:2x}{3:2x}{4:2x}{5:2x}",
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[2],
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[3],
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[4],
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[5],
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[6],
                                   (Int16)sidBytes[7]);
                    strSid.Append("-");
                    strSid.Append(strAuth);
                }
                else
                {
                    Int64 iVal = sidBytes[7] +
                         (sidBytes[6] << 8) +
                         (sidBytes[5] << 16) +
                         (sidBytes[4] << 24);
                    strSid.Append("-");
                    strSid.Append(iVal.ToString());
                }

                // Get sub authority count...
                int idxAuth = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < sSubAuthorityCount; i++)
                {
                    idxAuth = 8 + i * 4;
                    UInt32 iSubAuth = BitConverter.ToUInt32(sidBytes, idxAuth);
                    strSid.Append("-");
                    strSid.Append(iSubAuth.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceWarning(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            return strSid.ToString();
        }

Courtesy to https://dev.to/hbolajraf/c-search-ad-entry-by-objectsid-using-novell-directory-ldap-nuget-package-28il
We can see a working code that looks somewhat like yours. Try this code in isolation and see whether it works. If so and you still get the exception complaining about index being out of bounds, then it is very possible that you are simply having an issue at some other part of your code, some start index that goes beyond bounds.

You mention objectSid and objectGuid so it's unclear which one you actually need (or both), but the solution for both is similar. Both the Guid and SecurityIdentifier classes have constructors that accept a byte array.
For objectGuid:
var objectGuidBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ObjectGuid);
var guid = new Guid(objectGuidBytes);
Console.WriteLine(guid);

For objectSid:
var objectSidBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ObjectSid);
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(objectSidBytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine(sid);

